# Formatting a list of sentences extracted from text

Tags: python, string, list, formatting

I am trying to format a list neatly that I have extracted using regex. I would like to have each sentence in its own line and remove the `\n` characters:

```
words = ['billion']
sentences = [sentence for sentence in text_1 if any(
    w.lower() in sentence.lower() for w in words)]

print(sentences)
```

Image of current output:

[image]

Comment: provide the regex extracted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OP's image, `text_1` is a list of strings. To remove the newline `\n` characters from a string, you can use the string's `replace` method. To print each newline-removed sentence on its own line, you can use a simple `for` loop. Keeping the rest of the code intact, replace `print(sentences)` with:

```
for s in sentences:
    print(s.replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: thank you that is great! Can i remove indentations from the text that appear to be in there? just trying to clean it up and make a bulleted-style list of sentences

Comment: Yes, try this inside the print statement: `s.replace('\n', '').lstrip()`

Comment: If I've answered your question, kindly accept my answer.